Is it safe to connect UPS to external Li-ion battery pack, with integrated charger blocked by diode?
I hope below picture will tell what I am thinking about clearly.

Is it safe to do this? Or what problems does it have, and how to fix them?

Does the UPS expect 96 V battery? Are the chargers galvanically isolated?

Yes the UPS uses 96V external battery. As for chargers, I'll be careful to make sure they are galvanically isolated. Thank you for pointing out. Is there any other potential problem?

Just guesswork here but some software could be upset about the charge-discharge characteristics being way off due to the diode, throw an error code and trip the inverter. Test it?

I see. Will test with Lead-Acid battery first when diode arrives.
